# Does a Chrome screen recorder extension with no permissions have the ability to upload recorded data to a unknown server?

Tags: google-chrome, permissions, google-chrome-extensions, recording

For example, the [Screen Recorder for Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screen-recorder-for-googl/eclbecdgdoahkliaijlpkigldlkojjdn/related?hl=en-US) extension requires no permissions up front. When you try to make a recording, it will ask you what to share (whole desktop, window, or tab).

After you have made a recording, the app presumably has access to the recording.

Can it then upload that recording anywhere it wants? Or does it need permissions for that?

I'd like to keep my information secure, but Chrome's webstore does not make this very clear at all. Very shameful on Google's part for keeping these things cloudy to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any extension in Chrome (or any other browser) can use the browser's API
to access the internet.

As the extension is working as part of Chrome, it has Chrome's permissions
to access the internet.

The only way to find out if it uploads its data is to use a product
such as Wireshark to track its connections to the internet.
You may then block any such access in the firewall.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I'll have to go offline, use the screen recorder and save the video locally, then disable on uninstall the plugin before re-connecting. I do wish Network Access was a permission I could choose. Imagine how many people's naked photos and videos make their way onto the internet against their intention. I bet it happens!

Comment: @trusktr, **That's insufficient** as I believe an app has the ability to store information on uninstall. This means that if you reinstall or if you have other extensions, the info can be leaked. What is sufficient is to reformat the browser/OS before reconnecting to the internet.